# How do I launch Bonjour?

Tags: bonjour

I'm a complete Apple newbie - just bought my first mbp two days ago.

I'm trying to connect to my WD my book live NAS (working fine under my existing Linux set-up). The set-up instructions from WD tell me to launch Bonjour from Safari - but I can't find any reference to Bonjour in Safari - or any where else, for that matter!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you’re running a firewall behind a NAT router (which serves no point), ***Bonjour’s enabled and running by default.*** It’s used to discover and connect to other devices within your local network configuration (think of that W2P button on a router - it’s Apple’s software equivalent). To view Bonjour discoverable devices through Safari, go to:

**Safari > Preferences > Advanced > “Include Bonjour in The Bookmarks Menu.”**

I’ve never set up a WD MyBook “NAS”, but here’s an example of how Bonjour works through Safari.

The printer on my local network (S-2) is discoverable:
[image]

I’m able to manipulate its settings via my browser:

[image]

Comment: Any idea how to do this in Safari 11?

Answer (score 3):

You have to include it yourself. In Safari go to 'Preferences' > 'Advanced' and select "Include Bonjour" where you wish to - either in Bookmarks or in your Favorites bar.

[image]

Comment: Any idea how to do this in Safari 11?